# Joining temporal and spatial data

Tags: postgresql, index, psql, postgis

I have two tables in psql that I am trying to join based on certain attributes - they are very large - 17 M rows and 2.7 M rows respectively

```
mydb=> SELECT reltuples::bigint AS estimate FROM pg_class where relname='foo';
 estimate 
----------
17087196
(1 row)

mydb=> SELECT reltuples::bigint AS estimate FROM pg_class where relname='bar';
 estimate 
----------
  2763829
(1 row)
```

On both, I have created spatial indices with

```
CREATE INDEX foo_gix ON foo USING GIST (the_geom);
```

The query I am running is a point in polygon analysis based on data collected at historical time intervals - counting points in polygons when the timestamps on both tables match.  Points are locations of mobile phone connections (`bar_history` and `bar`) and polygons are buffers around certain areas (`foo_history`, `foo`)

It looks like this:

```
select s.id, s.place_id, s.time, count(l.location) as total
FROM foo_history as s LEFT JOIN foo as p ON s.place_id = p.id 
LEFT JOIN bar_history l ON ST_Contains(ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Centroid(p.polygon),
4326), 32615), 100), ST_Transform(l.location, 32615)) LEFT JOIN bar ON bar.phone_id = l.id
WHERE bar.network_id = 2
group by s.id LIMIT 5
```

This query returns results successfully in less than a few seconds.  However, when I add join by timestamps:

```
select s.id, s.place_id, s.time, count(l.location) as total
FROM foo_history as s LEFT JOIN foo as p ON s.place_id = p.id 
LEFT JOIN bar_history l ON ST_Contains(ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Centroid(p.polygon),
4326), 32615), 100), ST_Transform(l.location, 32615)) LEFT JOIN bar ON bar.phone_id = l.id
WHERE bar.network_id = 2
AND 
to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from l.time::timestamp) / 600 )) * 600) = 
to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from s.time::timestamp) / 600 )) * 600)
    group by s.id LIMIT 5
```

the query runs endlessly, even though nearly all of the timestamps will match each other from both tables.  I am not a database expert and would appreciate any suggestions on how to speed up this query or add some kind of index that might speed it up.

Comment: What is `to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from l.time::timestamp) / 600 )) * 600) = ` supposed to do?

Comment: That rounds a timestamp to the nearest 10-minute interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Time

This is really bad:

```
AND 
to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from l.time::timestamp) / 600 )) * 600) = 
to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from s.time::timestamp) / 600 )) * 600)
```

Instead, try to rewrite that in terms of `l.time`, ignoring epoch. I have no idea of the interval you want.

```
AND l.time BETWEEN s.time AND (s.time + '10 minutes');
```

Or whatever. If you're trying to assign arbitrary timestamps into 10 minutes intervals or whatever, there is no need to cast back to timestamp. You may consider writing your own function for convenience,

```
CREATE FUNCTION myIntervalExtract(ts timestamp with time zone)
RETURNS int
AS $$
  SELECT floor( extract(epoch FROM l.time::timestamp) / 600 )::int * 600;
$$ LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;
```

Now you can create a functional index on both `myIntervalExtract(l.time)` and `myIntervalExtract(s.time)` using the above. That will satisfy the join so long as you join

```
FROM l
JOIN s ON myIntervalExtract(l.time) = myIntervalExtract(s.time)
```

## GIS

```
ST_Contains(ST_Buffer()..)
```

This is also an antipattern. You'll want to rewrite that to `ST_DWithin`. you should also aim not to have `ST_Transform` in your join conditions. Instead, consider using `geography` on the table.

```
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON ST_DWithin(t1.polygeog, t2.geogpoint, distance_in_meters)
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, the issue is that both tables timestamps should be rounded to the nearest 10 minute - intervals `(01:00:00, 01:10:00, 01:20:00,...) `  Is it possible to rewrite `AND l.time BETWEEN s.time AND (s.time + '10 minutes');` to take that into account without extracting epoch?

Comment: @the_darkside updated.

Comment: thanks, this is very helpful. so I would have to just do `::geography` on both polygon and point?

Comment: using `geography` didn't speed up the query, but the time between method certainly did, thanks

Comment: @the_darkside no, you should be storing the types as geography and using `ST_DWithin` and then you create a GIST index on both the spatial columns. Then that too can be sped up with an index operations